# ros2 command not found. any fixes?

Tags: raspberry-pi, ros

I tried to run this command (ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake my_package) and it aint working

I tried to run this command (ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake my_package) according to this tutorial provided by articulated robotics (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_SyQXTL2XU&list=PLunhqkrRNRhYYCaSTVP-qJnyUPkTxJnBt&index=5)
I was getting the ros2: command not found for it.
Any idea on how i can fix this?

Comment: *it aint working* is not a useful problem description. Did you try searching this site for the error message you're getting (which you did not provide in your post)?

Answer (score 0):

Source your ROS workspace according to the [tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Configuring-ROS2-Environment.html#source-the-setup-files).

```
# Replace ".bash" with your shell if you're not using bash
# Possible values are: setup.bash, setup.sh, setup.zsh
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
```

It looks the video demonstration you linked did not show that.